# Nginx PHP server block returning 502 error

Tags: php, nginx, hosts

I am trying to create a simple server block on my local Nginx installation that will return a simple PHP index.php page. I have done this before with no problems whatsoever but in this instance I cannot seem to get it working and I have no idea why! I am getting a 502 error whenever I am trying to access the URL.

Here is my local hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       james-ESPRIMO-P420
127.0.0.1       st-davids-lab.dev
127.0.0.1       molecare.dev
127.0.0.1       st-davids-ire.dev
127.0.0.1       charity-site.dev
127.0.0.1       smaxtec.dev
127.0.0.1       product-viewer.dev
127.0.0.1       stdavids-brain.dev
127.0.0.1       http://php-parser.dev
127.0.0.1       php-parser.dev
```

And here is my conf file within the /etc/nginx/sites-available folder:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name php-parser.dev http://php-parser.dev;


        root /var/www/php-parser/;
        index index.php index.html;

        # Important for VirtualBox
        sendfile off;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            #rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php
        }

        location ~* \.php {
            include fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_cache off;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
        }
```

I have also created the symbolic link in the sites-enabled folder by executing the current command:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/phpparser.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

In my /var/www/php-parser/index.php file I have a simple die statement that should show this this is working when I access the URL php-parser.dev but this never gets hit.

Can anyone see what is going wrong here as it is infuriating! It's going to be something stupid!

Here is the output from the Nginx error log:

```
2016/08/03 11:01:55 [crit] 4830#4830: *34 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: php-parser.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "php-parser.dev"
```

Thanks

Comment: What does the error log say? Chances are it can't access the socket. Also, is SELinux enabled on your system?

Comment: I have added the output from the error log for the request

Comment: Ah, so the socket file doesn't exist. Do you have `php5-fpm` installed as a service? If not, check out [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-12-04) tutorial. Obviously,  you should change the commands accordingly depending on the system you're using.

Comment: Yes I did have it installed as a service but I Recently upgraded my Ubuntu installation and it seems to have played around with my installed packages! Will go and investigate if this is the problem and return. Thanks

Comment: `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;` <-- this probably is the problem, ensure nginx and php-fpm are both running, and check whether php-fpm uses sockets or connection ppols (`systemctl status php-fpm.service`, the precise name of php-fpm might vary, use `systemctl | grep php-fpm` to get the exact name). If you're using connection pools, the systemctl output should point to a php-fpm.conf file of sorts, in it you should be able to find an IP and port (eg 127.0.01:9000). Replace the socket line with `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;` and restart nginx

Comment: If you're not using connection pools, then perhaps double-check the path to the php5-fpm.sock file (`sudo updatedb && locate php-fpm.sock`)

Comment: My php5-fpm service isn't running but I also cannot install the php5-fpm package since upgrading Ubuntu. I get this error: Package php5 have no installation candidate

Comment: It was because my Nginx conf files were point to old PHP5 packages that don't exist anymore. I have provided an answer below. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems that when I upgraded Ubuntu it upgraded my PHP version to PHP7 and removed my PHP5 packages. My conf files was still pointing to the old PHP5 version so I simply added this into my default and necessary conf files:

fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;